# Are "used to" + {infinitive / gerund } equivalent?

Tags: idioms, complementation

In the phrase

> We’re all used to (some-special-word) *to mean* something different.

would it also be correct to switch the infinitive with the gerund form, resulting in:

> We’re all used to (some-special-word) *meaning* something different.

Comment: @Mistu4u I'm not sure about this *used of* vs *used to*  thing. Look for instance at this arbitrary internet example http://notreallyaustralian.blogspot.de/2009/03/day-13in-which-im-bitch.html. There you have: "That's how Tim is. I'm pretty used of it by now."

Comment: I suppose _Use of_ is colloquial. I could not find any dictionary reference of _Use of_. Hope somebody can shed some this doubt!

Comment: I've never heard 'used of' (native British speaker). Also, [see ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+of%2Cused+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20to%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "used to" is a very imprecise indication because it does not show whether you mean "to be used to something" meaning to be accustomed to sth or the defective verb "used to do",  when speaking of former habits or conditions. You have two totally different verbs. A look at a dictionary would be no bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are confusing two different constructions here.

Both employ the verb *use* in the broad sense “do habitually”. And in both, the verb is used today only with the -D form: *used*.

In one construction, *used* represents the past tense and is used with the *marked infinitive* of another verb—that is, the infinitive form with the particle *to* in front of it. In this case, *used* may mean **1)** simply “did habitually”, or it may imply **2)** “did then, but no longer do so”:

***used* + [*to*-infinitive]**
 1. When I was a kid we used [to swim] in the lake.
 2. People used [to believe] that the world is flat.

In the other construction, *used* is a *past participle* employed as an *adjective*. It is ordinarily preceded by a form of the verb *be*.

> ADDED: ... or, as Paola observes, a form of the verb *get*. But this would be deprecated in formal contexts — a form of *become* would be preferred.

In this case it is still employed with *to*—but now *to* is a **preposition** and must be followed by **1)** a noun or noun phrase, which may be **2)** a gerund or gerund phrase. In this case, *used* bears the sense “accustomed” or “inured”

***be used* + *to* + [NP]**
 1. As a sailor he was used to [**hardships**].
 2a. We are very used to [**being** misunderstood].
 2b. I am used to [Mike **borrowing** my bike].

That yields this, which I think is what you intend by the revised example in your question:

We are all used to [*democracy* **meaning** something different in different contexts].

Note that in both of these constructions, the collocation *used to* is pronounced with an unvoiced /s/ rather than the /z/ called for in ordinary uses of *used*. In dialogue you’ll often see this indicated with “useta*. In effect, *used to* is becoming a distinct modal, like *hafta* or *wanta*.

---

After you posted your link I did a quick-and-dirty Google on “get used of it”, and it is apparent that *used **of*** is coming into currency as an alternative to the second construction I describe. (If you perform the test for yourself, be warned that the number of hits Google reports at the top of the page is essentially meaningless.)

However, as this [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+used+of+it%2Cget+used+to+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows you, this is **not** Standard English. It may *become* Standard English someday, but it’s not there yet.

Comment: I agree about *get* normally being a less formal verb than others (see for example *"I had/got my car serviced yesterday"*); however, in this context I generally find sentences like *"I'm getting used to the heat"* instead of *becoming* or other verbs, both in language textbooks and in normal usage. I wonder whether it is due to the fact that my sources are normally British English.

Comment: *"Used of"* is not something I hear much or say at all, however - *"used to"* is something that I hear (and use) quite frequently in conversation. *"I still can't get used to this heat"*, *"I'm used to getting stuck in traffic every morning now"*, etc.

Comment: @StoneyB Now, if you could include the NP variant à la *used to Mike riding my bike* in your answer, and say, that would be the second sentence of the question, it would be perfect, and I would happily move the check mark to this answer.

Comment: @stacky-bit I've added *used to Mike riding my bike*, and reconstructed your example with *democracy* for the "special word".

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that the correct sentence is the second one.

In fact, the expressions ***be used*** and ***get used*** are formed by a verb followed by an adjective and a preposition, normally ***to***, which in turn may be followed by a noun or by a verb. As a rule, when a verb is preceded by a preposition, it is used in the gerund.

So, I would say

> *I'm used to riding my bike*

by which I mean to say that riding my bike is no new thing to me, I've done it often, but I could also say

> *I'm used to Mike riding my bike*

which indicates the fact that Mike frequently takes my bike and rides it, and I don't complain about it (or no longer do it...)

As for the possibility of using the preposition ***of*** instead of ***to*** in these sentences, I suppose it could be a regional form, but personally I've never seen it used.